# How do I produce this Greek letter koppa: Ϟ in pdfLaTeX?

Tags: pdftex, greek

I have been trying to typeset the character `GREEK LETTER KOPPA`. It has not been working. I know the Unicode number (U+03DE), and tried the command `^^3de` and `^^3DE`. Neither worked. I also tried `\char` and `\char"`, but those didn't work either, other symbols get produced.

Does anybody have an idea as to how I can get my computer to typeset the symbol Ϟ?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}  
\usepackage[ngerman, polutonikogreek]{babel}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{arevmath}  
\usepackage{lmodern}  
\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont  
\usepackage{geometry}  
 \geometry{  
 a4paper,  
 top=30mm,  
 left=25mm,  
 right=20mm,  
 bottom=20mm,  
 }  

\begin{document}  
\selectlanguage{ngerman}  

$\Koppa$  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you use either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX?

Answer (score 9):

Using [`arevmath`](http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LUCR/Math/mathpackages/arevmath-symbols.pdf) package you have the request symbol.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arevmath}
\begin{document}

$\Koppa$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tried, and I get the following error message:

! LaTeX Error: Command `\qoppa' already defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.28 ...Symbol{\qoppa}{\mathord}{extraitalic}{162}
                                                   % uni03D9
?

Comment: I have not errors, sorry. The command is `\Koppa` and not `\qoppa`.

Comment: @rensemil - It looks like you're loading some font-related packages in addition to `arevmath`. Have you tried *not* loading `arevmath` and typing `\Koppa` (in math mode, presumably)?

Comment: I know. That error message even occurs if I don't type \Koppa in the document. As soon as I add the arevmath package, the error message pops up.

Comment: @Mico Thank you very much for your technical support.

Comment: @rensemil In my TeX Live installation, a command `\qoppa` is defined by the packages `teubner`, `alphabeta`, and `boisik`, and the Babel language definitions `greek`, `ibygreek`, and `bgreek`, as well as by `arevmath`.  Are you loading any of those?

Comment: @rensemil - Which font-related packages do you load at present?

Comment: @zwol Thank you! That did it! Because of the polutonikogreek package, there was an error. I've got it working now!

Answer (score 6):

You have it in the `cm-unicode` fonts, to be used with `xelatex`. They also have the `archaic koppa`. If you can type it directly on your keyboard, `XeLaTeX` will understand it. Other than that I defined two commands to obtain them (note the hexadecimal code is not the official unicode hexadecimal number):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\def\koppa{\char "03DF}
\def\archaickoppa{\char "03D9}

\begin{document}

koppa: \qquad \LARGE\koppa\qquad ϟ

{\normalsize archaic koppa: \qquad}\archaickoppa\qquad ϙ


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Bernard Hi, have you seen my message for \vast command?

Comment: @rensemil: I think this message is for me. It's unrelated to your question.@Sebastiano>. I've found it this morning (grazie tante!), but didn't have time to look at your link. I've taken alook this evening. It seems to be a command to obtain delimiters still larger than `\Bigg`. I dihad never heard of this construct, but I'm no guru.

Comment: My compliments for your answer that I have upvoted.

Comment: Thanks for your kind appreciation, @Sebastiano!

Answer (score 4):

If you have a font on your system that you know has that character you can use a package such as [`fontspec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathspec) or [`mathspec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathspec) to typeset your document (either whole or part, as you prefer) in that font.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know either of those things.

Comment: Fair enough. For what it's worth, some Google fonts that support that character are Noto Serif, Cardo and Tinos (all serif; some sans serif ones are Noto Sans, Fira Sans and Arimo).

Comment: P.S. I've just noticed that you specify pdfLaTeX in your question title; the two packages I suggested require XeLaTeX. (Sorry about that!)

Comment: @Miztli Don't worry I voted the same you for the effort and the correct answer.

Comment: I chose XeLaTeX instead, and suddendly, all my greek letters are not being shown anymore. arevmath still gives the error message when loading.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include a MWE (minimal working example)?

Comment: @Miztli I'm new to stackexchange, how do I do that?

Comment: Create a separate very simple (stripped down to the bare bones, including only the packages and content relevant for this issue) version of the code you have, click "edit" below your question and then include it in a code block (use the button with two curly braces).

Comment: The issue is solved for me when I move `arevmath` to the top of the preamble.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one definition that works with the modern toolchain.  It requires LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX and an OpenType or TrueType font containing the glyph.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase }
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}[Scale = 1.0]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}

\newcommand\koppa{\ifmmode%
{\mathord{\textnormal{^^^^03de}}}\else%
^^^^03de\fi}

\begin{document}
Here is the symbol \koppa.

\( \koppa = \koppa_{\koppa_\koppa} \)
\end{document}
```

[image: DejaVu font sample]

There are other ways to declare the symbol as well, including loading a font containing Ϟ as a symbol alphabet and using `\DeclareMathSymbol`, or loading the symbol in text mode from a `\newfontfamily` declared with `fontspec`, or defining it with `\newunicodechar`, or loading all Greek letters from that Unicode block with `ucharclasses`, or finding an OpenType math font that has the glyph, or plain TeX `\char"03DE`, or `\symbol{"03DE}`.

Comment: Surely also your answer is very good. I have appreciated also this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the inclusion of the `polutonikogreek` package. Without it, everything works just fine.